Jupyter notebook snowflake connection
Trying to connect to snowflake database
pip install snowflake-connector-python

getting message
Requirement already satisfied: snowflake-connector-python in c:\program files\python312\lib\site-packages (3.11.0)
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
con = snowflake.connector.connect(    
    user='',    
    authenticator='externalbrowser',    
    account='',    
    warehouse='',    
    schema='GOLD',    
    database=''    
)
getting error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package`

when I check the packages installed pip --list I see snowflake-connector-python 3.11.0
I'm using Python 3.12.4
how to resolve this error?

Couple of solutions for you:

Try installing the package directly locally in your Jupyter notebook instead of via the terminal, as in the latter case it would be a globally installed package so you'll need to set the PATH properly
Uninstall snowflake first (pip uninstall snowflake), then install the entire package again (pip install snowflake-connector-python==3.11.0). Having Snowflake installed prior to the snowflake-connector-python can cause issues in the init.py file

